# How to run Tensorboard in parallel

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorboard

https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepRecommender

According to the above page, I tried to run the NVIDIA's DeepRecommender program.After I activated the pytorch, I run the program as below but it failed.

[I run this Command]

$ python run.py --gpu_ids 0 \
 --path_to_train_data Netflix/NF_TRAIN \
 --path_to_eval_data Netflix/NF_VALID \
 --hidden_layers 512,512,1024 \
 --non_linearity_type selu \
 --batch_size 128 \
 --logdir model_save \
 --drop_prob 0.8 \
 --optimizer momentum \
 --lr 0.005 \
 --weight_decay 0 \
 --aug_step 1 \
 --noise_prob 0 \
 --num_epochs 12 \
 --summary_frequency 1000

[The comments of the Guide.]

> Note that you can run Tensorboard in parallel
>
> $ tensorboard --logdir=model_save

[My Question]

The guide says as above.I don't know how to run in parallel.Please tell me the way. Shoud I open 2 terminal  windows?

[Enviroment]

The detail of the enviroment is as follow.
---> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, python 3.6, Pytorch 1.2.0, CUDA V10.1.168

[The 1st trial]

After I activated the pytorch,

```
 $source activate pytorch

 $python run.py --gpu_ids 0 \  (The long parameters are abbreviated here.)
```

[The Error messages of the 1st trial]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 13, in 
    from logger import Logger
  File "/home/user/NVIDIA_DeepRecommender/DeepRecommender-mp_branch/logge                                                                                                 r.py", line 4, in 
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

[The 2nd trial]

After I activated the tensorflow-gpu,

```
 $ source activate tensorflow-gpu

 $python run.py --gpu_ids 0 \  (The long parameters are abbreviated here.)
```

[The Error messages of the 2nd trial.]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 2, in 
    import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

[Expected result]

> $ python run.py --gpu_ids 0 \
>    The program can run with no error and finish training the model.

Comment: When it is stated that you can run tensorboard in parallel it indeed means you can simply open another terminal window, and start the tensorboard command. The only thing to keep in mind there is that the parameter you specify in 'logdir' (model_save) points to an actual folder (so it should be started from the same folder).  This answers you initial question, but this does not explain the other issues (missing tensorflow and/or torch) that you mentioned afterwards.

Comment: Hi amo-ej1, thank you for your answer.

initial question> $ tensorboard --logdir=model_save

According to your advice, I opened another terminal window and run the command "tensorboard --logdir= 'actual dir' ".So initial question was solved.
But the program failed as before.

Answer (score 2):

Try either installing `tensorflow-gpu` in your `pytorch` environment or `pytorch` in your `tensorflow-gpu` environemnt and use that environment to run your program.

Comment: Thank you, but I have already installed both pytorch and tensorflow-gpu.

Comment: You mean you have pytorch installed inside tensflow-gpu environement? because it seems like you have two separate envs for pytorch and tensorflow and you are activating them using `source activate tensorflow-gpu`.  If this is indeed the case, when you are inside `tensorflow-gpu` env,  it would have no access to pytorch module.

Comment: Hi  Usman Ali ,

  I was able to understand the meaning of your first comment.
According to your first advice, I re-installed pytorch in my tensorflow-gpu environemnt and re-tried to run this program in this eivironment.

In this time, I was able to run it successfully.
Thank you very much.